# Hibernate+Spring - configure session before use

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session, jpa

I have a Spring Boot application with JPA/Hibernate. I would like to have an extra operation executed each and every time the session is created - namely `Session.setCacheMode`.

I do not want to do it on all public entry points to my app, so a new annotation with AOP interceptor doesn't seem like a good idea. Just do it once for the entire application and forget.

With this stack, how can I get access to the `Session` and do something with it before it's handed to the application? Does Spring or Hibernate expose a hook where I could add my callback/interceptor/listener?